# in fact, in point of fact, as a matter of fact

Tags: meaning, expressions, expression-choice

Today I was tempted to write "in point of fact" and immediately wondered if this expression differed at all from "in fact" or "as a matter of fact." Dictionaries define one with the others. Ultimately, I chose "in fact" simply because it is more concise, and I doubt that I would ever use "in point of fact" or "as a matter of fact" if they are equivalent.

I understand that "in fact" is much more commonly used (perhaps in part because it can be comfortably used mid-sentence, whereas "in point of fact" and "as a matter of fact" are too clunky or interruptive mid-sentence).

However, does anyone know of a salient difference between these three expressions? Semantic or otherwise? In what circumstances would one sacrifice conciseness and choose "in point of fact" or "as a matter of fact" over "in fact"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, though it carries the connotation of *something true, though unlikely*, ***in fact*** is more subtle and can pass unnoticed more easily than the other two more wordy phrases. Also, being made of only two words, *in fact* is more flexible as regards word order. It can even sneak in between the auxiliary and the past participle:

> She knew she *could have*, ***in fact***, *obtained* all of this information from Carolyn. (*[Time Waits for No One](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Time_Waits_for_No_One/8Rf2AQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, by Linda Ellen Fletcher, 2013)

It can be used in this order without commas too:

> Likewise, just because an agent acts from a reasons-responsive mechanism, this does not mean that she *could have* ***in fact*** *done* otherwise at the time. (*[Free Will: The Basics](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Time_Waits_for_No_One/8Rf2AQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, by Meghan Griffith, 2021)

In these two examples, the attempt of replacing *in fact* with either of two other expressions would be, as you say, rather "chunky".

However, if you want to ***emphasise*** the opposition contained in the meaning of these phrases, it helps to use the longer variants. Especially ***[in point of fact](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in-point-of-fact)***, being the most formal of all three, announces the contrast more vividly than the discrete *in fact*. Compare:

> - It's odd that you would criticize me for that when, ***in point of fact,*** I never said such a thing.

and

> - It's odd that you would criticize me for that when ***in fact*** I never said such a thing.

I agree that ***as a matter of fact*** is not so formal, we hear it all the time. Very often, we use a longer phrase like this one as a speech cliché, when we want to "buy some time" to find the right words to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

The three expression are actually synonyms with different registers. *As a matter of fact and in point of fact* sound  more formal and as [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20fact%2Cin%20point%20of%20fact%2Cas%20a%20matter%20of%20fact&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cin%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20point%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20point%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20point%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cas%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BAs%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0)  shows they are by far less common than the more popular and colloquial  *in fact*. It appears that only *as a matter of fact* has a specific etymology.

**As a matter of fact:**

Etymology: (from Etymonline)

> - also matter of fact, 1570s as a noun, **originally a legal term (translating Latin res facti)**, "that portion of an enquiry concerned with the truth or falsehood of alleged facts," opposed to matter of law. As an adjective from 1712.

Meaning:

> - actually in (point of) fact I did vote for her, as a matter of fact.
> - Usage notes: used to emphasize the truth of what you are saying.
>   ( from Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

**In point of fact:**

> - in reality or actuality; "in fact, it was a wonder anyone survived"; "painters who are in fact anything but unsophisticated"; "as a matter of fact, he is several inches taller than his father"

**In fact**:

> - in reality or actuality; "in fact, it was a wonder anyone survived"; "painters who are in fact anything but unsophisticated"; "as a matter of fact, he is several inches taller than his father"

As a side note, I personally tend to use the expression  *as a matter of fact* in  formal business conversations.

( source: TFD) .

Comment: _As a matter of fact_ sounds perfectly colloquial to me—I use it frequently in normal, everyday conversation. And there is one case where it’s only viable option: when it’s used to indicate some level of surprise at the following statement (your own or your interlocutor’s), or if the statement corrects a falsehood or misconception: “And, having done all these tests, did you discover anything new?” — “As a matter of fact, I did, yes.” // “It’s not very good, is it?” — “As a matter of fact, it’s _very_ good!” The other two options here both sound quite odd and jarring to my ears in this context.

Comment: Could you clarify Josh? The examples below the 2nd and 3rd expressions are the same. They appear interchangeable. Do you have examples to illustrate the difference in register?

Comment: Definition are very similar because, as I said, they are synonyms. To me the first two expressions sound bit more formal and are less common as NGram clearly shows ( and as yourself noted in your question).'As a matter of fact' used to emphasise the truth about what you are saying is used colloquially but it is less common compared to 'actually' for instance. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=actually%2Cas+a+matter+of+fact&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cactually%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

I would use *"in fact"* to introduce a contradictory statement.

> "There shouldn't be any people on the boat. In fact, there are two of
>   them left."

and I would use *"as a matter of fact"* to support a previous statement.

> "There shouldn't be any people on the boat. As a matter of fact,
>   everyone left the boat already 30 minutes ago."

However, I'm not a native speaker and I might be wrong.